# Magento 1.9.2.4 Gap Below Header in Responsive Design

Tags: css, magento-1.9

I cant figure out how to remove the gap between the header and the main content. According to Firefox Firebug it is controlled by the main-container col2-left-layout class. But changing either of these doesn't remove the gap.

http://ultraviolet-water-treatment-systems.co.uk/sl-dev/

Any help please?

Thank you,

Kirsty

Comment: Looks like you need a password to log on to that site

Comment: Not able to see your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Magento's RWD (Responsive Web Design) theme. 
There is padding on the `.main-container` if that helps your situation:

**In /skin/frontend/default/rwd/css/styles.css** add:

```
body .main-container.col2-left-layout {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

I prepended body to try and override some existing styles that may prevent that space. If this still doesn't work then try adding **!important** before the semi-colon

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou Chris, it worked!! I had to include the !important

Comment: No worries there Kirsty! Come back anytime!Be sure to mark this as answered so anyone else can benefit :)